# Gunicorn processes don't get stopped via Supervisor

Tags: gunicorn, supervisord

I've a supervisor configuration to start a flask app which runs by:

```
/venv/bin/gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0:5000 -w 10 -k eventlet
```

I'd 2 questions:

1. When I run:

   `ps aux | grep gunicorn`
   I only see 5-6 gunicorn processes. Why is that. Doesn't -w option states that there will be 10 proccesses.
2. When I run:

   `sudo supervisorctl stop <process_name>` . Not all processes get killed. Why is that? I've to manually kill other processes.

The other settings in supervisor are as follows:

```
numprocs = 1
directory = /home/ubuntu/<Project Folder>
user = ubuntu
autostart = true
autorestart = true
startsecs = 3
startretries = 5
exitcodes = 0,2
stopsignal = QUIT
stopasgroup = true
stopwaitsecs = 3
```

Comment: Are there any Daemon threads in your application? Could you also check by setting the graceful time out to a lesser value say 1 second and try?

Comment: @Praneeth There are no settings for daemon threads in my configuration. I've updated the question with other supervisor configurations.

Comment: Could you check by setting the graceful_timeout in gunicorn settings? This would be an argument to gunicorn command line. More information on this link http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#settings